# Problems with SUM() and alias with CakePHP 3

Tags: mysql, cakephp, sum, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to do a `SELECT` with a `SUM` but I have a probleme with aliases. CakePHP 3 is used here.

In my controller, I do :

```
$preparations->find('all',
                [   'fields' => ['SUM(Preparations.qty) as sumqty', 'order_id', 'product_id'],
                    'conditions' => ['order_id IN ' => $ids],
                    'contain' => ['Products'],
                    'group' => 'product_id'
                ]);
```

But the query i have with this is :

```
SELECT SUM(Preparations.qty) as sumqty AS SUM(`Preparations__qty`) AS `sumqty`, Preparations.order_id AS `Preparations__order_id`, Preparations.product_id AS `Preparations__product_id`
```

`SUM()` is written twice. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Use the query builder. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions for how to use SQL functions with the query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
'fields' => ['sumqty'=>'SUM(Preparations.qty)', 'order_id', 'product_id']
```

Comment: Even better use the query builder as already mentioned by burzum.